# MySQL There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database (foreign keys)

Tags: mysql

**SQL Statement:**

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `ceramica`.`productos` 

ADD INDEX `id_categoria_idx` (`id_categoria` ASC) VISIBLE;

;

ALTER TABLE `ceramica`.`productos` 

ADD CONSTRAINT `id_categoria`


  FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`)

  REFERENCES `ceramica`.`categorias` (`id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near '' at line 2

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `ceramica`.`productos` 

ADD INDEX `id_categoria_idx` (`id_categoria` ASC) VISIBLE
```

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? Remove the tag for the DBMS you're not using.

Comment: Seems that `ASC` should be outside the closing `)` to the right? ... not sure about the `VISIBLE` reference?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your SQL commands, however you have an empty statement between them which is probably causing the problem.